# Convert nested array of values to a tree structure

Tags: javascript, algorithm, array, tree

I have a nested array that represents a parent child relationship, that I need to convert to a tree structure.

*Example nested array*

```
list = [
        ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1'],
        ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
        ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-2'],
        ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
        ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-2', 'lvl-3 item-2', 'lvl-4 item-1'],
    ]
```

Each tree node has the following structure.

```
{
    name: "item",
    parent: "parent_name",
    children: []
}
```

Each item in the nested array represents a level in the object.

*Expected JSON*

```
{
  "name": "0",
  "parent": null,
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "lvl-1 item-1",
      "parent": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "lvl-2 item-1",
          "parent": "lvl-1 item-1",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "lvl-3 item-1",
              "parent": "lvl-2 item-1",
              "children": []
            },
            {
              "name": "lvl-3 item-2",
              "parent": "lvl-2 item-1",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "lvl-1 item-2",
      "parent": "0",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "lvl-2 item-1",
          "parent": "lvl-1 item-2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "lvl-3 item-1",
              "parent": "lvl-2 item-1",
              "children": []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "lvl-2 item-2",
          "parent": "lvl-1 item-2",
          "children": [
            {
              "name": "lvl-3 item-2",
              "parent": "lvl-2 item-2",
              "children": [
                {
                  "name": "lvl-4 item-1",
                  "parent": "lvl-3 item-2",
                  "children": []
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The code below is what I came up with, but there is a lot of room for improvement.

First I loop each item in the list and all of its children.

I add each level name to a parent array so I can navigate it later to find existing child objects. Once I hit the end of the child loop I add the current level to the parent for use on the next iteration.

Once I've reached the end of the parents for loop I check if the current name exists in the children and add it if not.

This was produced with a lot of trial and error, I'm struggling to explain it accurately.

Can someone help me to review this code, to better understand it and improve it.

I had trouble getting the initial structure to work, I ended up creating what I believe is a redundant object with a `children` field so that it matched the expected format.

Any help will be much appreciated. If there is anything I haven't explained clearly please let me know.

```js
list = [
    ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1'],
    ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
    ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-2'],
    ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
    ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-2', 'lvl-3 item-2', 'lvl-4 item-1'],
];

console.log(nestedArrayToJson(list));

function nestedArrayToJson(structure) {
    const top_item = '0';

    let data = {
        children: [
            {
                name: top_item,
                parent: null,
                children: [],
            }],
    };

    for(let i = 0; i < structure.length; i++) {
        let parents = [top_item];
        for(let j = 0; j < structure[i].length; j++) {
            let obj = data;
            for(parent of parents) {
                obj = obj.children.find(o => o.name === parent);
            }
            const name = structure[i][j];
            if(!obj.children.find(o => o.name === name)) {
                obj.children.push({
                    name,
                    parent,
                    children: [],
                });
            }
            parents.push(structure[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return data.children[0];
}
```

### Updated Script

```js
list = [
  ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1'],
  ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
  ['lvl-1 item-1', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-2'],
  ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-1', 'lvl-3 item-1'],
  ['lvl-1 item-2', 'lvl-2 item-2', 'lvl-3 item-2', 'lvl-4 item-1']
]

function createTree(arr, topItem = "Top") {
  const node = (name, parent = null) => ({
    name,
    parent,
    children: []
  });
  const addNode = (parent, child) => {
    parent.children.push(child);

    return child;
  };
  const findNamedNode = (name, parent) => {
    for (const child of parent.children) {
      if (child.name === name) {
        return child
      }
      const found = findNamedNode(name, child);
      if (found) {
        return found
      }
    }
  };

  const top = node(topItem);
  let current;

  for (const children of arr) {
    current = top;
    for (const name of children) {
      const found = findNamedNode(name, current);
      current = found ? found : addNode(current, node(name, current.name));
    }
  }

  return top;
}

console.log(createTree(list, 'lvl-0 item-1'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Vernacular

Naming is very important and it starts by using the correct terminology.

There is no such thing as a JSON object as you use the term. There are JSON strings and JSON files. There is also a [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON) built-in Object. It provides an API to help convert between Objects and JSON strings

JavaScript uses [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) to store data in the form of properties.

Objects can be converted to JSON string using [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), or can be created from a JSON string using [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Not all object can be converted to JSON, while all valid JSON strings can be converted to an Object.

Your question title makes no sense...

> *"Convert nested array of values to a JSON object"*

*"JSON object"* is more meaningfully as [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure))

"Convert nested array into a tree"

### Style

- The variables `data` and `parent` should be declared as constants [`const`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const) as the references they hold do not change.
- The JavaScript naming convention is [camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) try to avoid using [snake_case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case). Eg the name `top_item` should be `topItem`
  The only time that snake_case is used is for some types of constants, in which case we use use SNAKE_UPPER_CASE.
- When possible (you don't need the array index) use a [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop rather than a [`for(;;)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop

### Code logic

#### Functions

Good code tries to avoid doing too much in one function. Breaking the code into distinct tasks and assigning those tasks to functions make it easier to manage as the complexity starts to grow.

You create the node object in two places. Good source code avoids repetition. The most conman way to avoid repetition is to create functions that do the same or similar things via a call.

You need to search the node to locate where to add new child nodes. The simplest way to search a tree is via a recursive function. Recursive functions exploit the similarity of nested data to reduce the complexity of the code.

#### Avoid redundancies

There is no need to create the `data` object as a top level parent. The child of `data`, `data.children[0]` can serve as the top parent.

### Rewrite

We can rewrite the code breaking it into smaller functions.

There are 3 functions in the main one

1. `node` creates a new node
2. `addNode` adds a node to a parent node
3. `findNamedNode` will find a node with a name. If that node does not exist it returns `undefined`

The main body of the function just iterated each array, searching for each node by name. If one is found it moves to the next. If no node is found it creates and adds a new one.

```
function createTree(structure, topItem = "Top") {
    const node = (name, parent = null) => ({name, parent, children: []});
    const addNode = (parent, child) => (parent.children.push(child), child);
    const findNamedNode = (name, parent) => {
        for (const child of parent.children) {
            if (child.name === name) { return child }
            const found = findNamedNode(name, child);
            if (found) { return found }            
        }
    }
    const TOP_NAME = "Top";
    const top = node(TOP_NAME);
    var current;

    for (const children of structure) {
        current = top;
        for (const name of children) {
            const found = findNamedNode(name, current);
            current = found ? found : addNode(current, node(name, current.name));
        }
    }
    return top;
}
```

To make sure it all worked (no typos or idiotic coder intrusion) the snippet run it once on a simple data set.

```js
logTree(createTree(data()));

function createTree(structure) {
    const node = (name, parent = null) => ({name, parent, children: []});
    const addNode = (parent, child) => (parent.children.push(child), child);
    const findNamed = (name, parent) => {
        for (const child of parent.children) {
            if (child.name === name) { return child }
            const found = findNamed(name, child);
            if (found) { return found }            
        }
    }
    const TOP_NAME = "Top", top = node(TOP_NAME);
    for (const children of structure) {
        let par = top;
        for (const name of children) {
            const found = findNamed(name, par);
            par = found ? found : addNode(par, node(name, par.name));
        }
    }
    return top;
}



















   function data() { return [['A1', 'B1'],['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],['A1', 'B1', 'C2'],['A2', 'B1', 'C1'],['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D1'],['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D2'],['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D3'],['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D4'],['A2', 'B2', 'C2', 'D5'],['A2', 'B3', 'C1', 'D1'],['A3', 'B1', 'C1', 'D1'],['A3', 'B1', 'C1', 'D2'], ['A3', 'B1', 'C1', 'D3']]; }





/*=============================================================================*/
// Support code unrelated to answer
function log(textContent) {
    info.appendChild(Object.assign(document.createElement("div"),{textContent}));
}    
function logTree(parent, indent = "", end) {
    const tail = parent.children.length > 0 ? "┬" : "─";
    if(end){
        log(indent + "└──┬─" + "►parent: " + parent.parent);
        log(indent + "   └" + tail + "►name..: " + parent.name);
        indent +="    ";
    } else {
        log(indent + "├──┬─" + "►parent: " + parent.parent);
        log(indent + "│  └" + tail + "►name..: " + parent.name);
        indent +="│   ";
    }
    var idx = 0;
    for (const child of parent.children) {
        logTree(child, indent, (idx++ === parent.children.length -1));
    }
}
```

```css
body {background:black}
#info {color:#CC0;font-size:smaller;white-space:pre-wrap;}
```

```html
<code id="info"></code>
```

Comment: Definitely some good points here.  Names of things are much simpler in Python, lists, dicts, tuples etc. everything JS is an object. I often call them associative arrays from my experience of PHP.  Not sure why I went for JSON object, I thought it described the structure more clearly, perhaps not. Take your point on the underscore vs camel case, I've been writing a lot of python lately and it slipped in. Will have a read through the code properly and have another crack it thanks so much for the pointers. First up will make the switch to `for of`s.

Comment: I've updated the title and description to more clearly describe what I'm doing. I see what you are doing with the functions at the top, it reads much more clearly.

Comment: Thanks so much for reviewing this, this is a really good, clean solution. There are a couple of points to improve. It should use either `topItem` or `TOP_NAME` to set the top item name, I've set it up to use the `topItem` so you have the option of changing it and removed the latter. I'm not sure of the meaning of `const addNode = (parent, child) => (parent.children.push(child), child);`. It looks like it should just push the child. I've removed `, child` after `push` and brackets. Lastly I renamed `structure` to `nested_array` to make that slightly clearer too.

Comment: Ah I see, I've had to put the `, child` part back in. I'll try to work out the meaning of it.

Comment: So this is using `(parent, child) => (parent.children.push(child), child);` Comma Expression to return the child after it pushes it. Pretty cool. I've switched it out for a more verbose `(parent, child) => {parent.children.push(child); return child;};` which I find easier to understand. I can see myself coming to like Comma Expressions though, nice to know, thanks again.